# How to get PropertyDescriptor of a subproperty

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get the PropertyDescriptor of a subproperty of my object from a string. In order to sort a collection based on that property afterwards.

I have provided the method with a string like "Subobject.Subproperty" but the PropertyDescriptor is null

```cs
PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(MyParentObject)).Find("MyChildObject.MySubProperty", true);
//....
items = items.OrderBy(y => prop.GetValue(y)).ToList();
```

In the end I get an exception caused by prop being null.

Comment: there is no such thing like "subproperty" ... did you mean property of other object which is property of first object?

Comment: Get the value of the property called `Subobject` then get the property of that value. But perhaps you can explain what you are really trying to do here?

Comment: @DavidG Im using Telerik on WPF and I need to create my own RadGridView sorting logic, so I was expecting of getting the sorting property from the DataMemerBinding... I'll try what you said

Comment: Since the bindings of the RadGridView had references to a diferent amount of objects on the route I ended un creating a switch that returns the appropiate Func<>